# i'm unable to get list of all the users who joined channel through presence in elixir, phoenix

Tags: sockets, elixir, phoenix-framework, channel

this is a quiz channel and after joining I want to get all the users who joined all the quizzes
quiz channel

```
def join("quiz:" <> id, _params, socket) do
    presence = Nuton.Presence.list("quiz:" <> id)

    if presence == %{} do
      send(self(), {:after_join_quiz, id})

      response = %{message: "you can now listen"}

      {:ok, response, socket}
    else
      quiz = "quiz:#{id}"
      %{^quiz => %{metas: metas}} = presence

      if Enum.count(metas) > 1 do
        {:error, %{reason: "Some other user already accepted the invitation"}}
      else
        send(self(), {:after_join_quiz, id})

        response = %{message: "you can now listen"}
        :ok = ChannelWatcher.monitor(:quiz, self(), {__MODULE__, :leave, [id]})
        {:ok, response, socket}
      end
    end
  end
def handle_info({:after_join_quiz, id}, socket) do
    presence = Presence.list(socket)
    if presence == %{} do
      {:ok, _} =
        Presence.track(socket, "quiz:" <> id, %{
          user_name: socket.assigns.current_user.username,
          user_id: socket.assigns.current_user.id,
          quiz_id: id
        })

      {:noreply, socket}
    else
      {:ok, _} =
        Presence.track(socket, "quiz:" <> id, %{
          user_name: socket.assigns.current_user.username,
          user_id: socket.assigns.current_user.id,
          quiz_id: id
        })

      Core.Endpoint.broadcast(
        "user:all",
        "invitation:decline",
        %{message: "Some other user already accepted the invitation"}
      )

      {:noreply, socket}
    end
  end
```

with specific `quiz_id` I can get all the user who joined the channel but with all I cant is there any issue in my code plz check if it is
Controller

```
quiz_users = Nuton.Presence.list("quiz:all")
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to cycle through all of the channels, somehow, to get that information. I believe there was a PR to get this info, before, actually, so you can cycle through all.

What would be better: if you have the socket join 2 channels, like a "lobby" or "all" channel and then each individual channel. When you track, you can specify the string for the topic instead of only putting in the socket:

`track(socket, "quiz:all", socket.assigns.user.id,%{})`